# Python Selenium/WebDriver Exception: Failed to convert script to String

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am new in selenium. What I want to do is to execute javascript function through python. And use the value returned by javascript function. I am stuck with above error. Please help me.
This is my js code:

```html
var doc = ""
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")
var s = p[0].parentElement
for (var i=0; i<s.childElementCount;i++)
{
  var a = s.children[i]
  scrap(a)
}

result()

function scrap(a)
{
  if (a.tagName == "H1")
    doc = doc +a.innerText
  else if (a.tagName == "H2") {
    doc = doc +a.innerText
  }
  else if (a.tagName == "H2") {
    doc = doc +a.innerText
  }
  else if (a.tagName == "H3") {
    doc = doc +a.innerText
  }
  else if (a.tagName == "H4") {
    doc = doc +a.innerText
  }
  else if (a.tagName == "P") {
    var j = a.childElementCount
 

      doc = doc +a.innerText

  }
  else if (a.tagName == "img") {
    doc = doc +a.innerText
  }
  else if (a.tagName == "li") {
    doc = doc +a.innerText
  }
  doc = doc + "\n"
}

function result()
{
  return "doc"
}
```

And this the python script:

```
js = open("generalized.js", "r").readlines()   // js code
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
result = driver.execute_script(js) // string returned by js function is saved in result
doc = open(path,"w")
doc.write(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines()` returns list, `driver.execute_script` expects a single string. Try to read the file as a string

```
js = open("generalized.js", "r").read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
js = open("generalized.js", "r").readlines()
```

This is returning a list of strings not a string.

Try to join the result to a string:

```
result = driver.execute_script("".join(js))
```

or read as string:

```
js = open("generalized.js", "r").read()
```